# Partial View is not getting loaded

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have 2 views and one of them is a Partial View. But when i run it, Partial view is not displayed getting displayed. Am i missing anything?

Code:
    Index

```
 <div>
   @Html.PartialView(_Home, Model);
 </div>

 _Home:

  <div>
    <table>
       <tr> 
         <td> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name) </td>
       </tr>
  </div>
```

Comment: I guess you missed "something" here `@Html.PartialView(_Home, Model);`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Html.PartialView("_Home", Model)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    @Html.Partial("_Home", model);
</div>
```